# How do I import a feed in a node?

Tags: nodes, 8, feeds, importing-exporting

I was looking for a solution to import RSS Feeds as nodes. We need to make modifications and add more fields to the content. This would have been easy in Drupal 7 with Feeds Importer, but it doesn't appear that there is a viable alternative for Drupal 8.

What would be the best way to import a feed directly to a node?

Comment: You could use core aggregator instead if you don't feel like contributing to Feeds module development.

Comment: Does aggregator publish the RSS Feeds to nodes?

I thought it just displayed the feed.

Comment: It imports things as custom entities.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution is described in:

https://ohthehugemanatee.org/blog/2017/06/07/stop-waiting-for-feeds-module-how-to-import-remote-feeds-in-drupal-8/

1) Download and enable migrate_plus and migrate_tools modules. You should be doing this with composer, but I won’t judge. Just get them into your codebase and enable them. Migrate Plus provides plugins for core Migrate, so you can parse remote XML, JSON, CSV, or even arbitrary spreadsheet data. Migrate Tools gives us drush commands for running migrations.

2) Write your Migration configuration in text, and paste it into the configuration import admin page (admin/config/development/configuration/single/import), or import it another way. I’ve included a starter YAML just below, you should be able to copypasta, change a few values, and be done in time for tea.

3) Add a line to your system cron to run drush migrate -y my_rss_importer at whatever interval you like.

Below is a YAML file which you should adjust:

```
id: my_rss_importer
label: 'Import my RSS feed'
status: true

source:
  plugin: url
  data_fetcher_plugin: http
  urls: 'https://example.com/feed.rss'
  data_parser_plugin: simple_xml

  item_selector: /rss/channel/item
  fields:
    -
      name: guid
      label: GUID
      selector: guid
    -
      name: title
      label: Title
      selector: title
    -
      name: pub_date
      label: 'Publication date'
      selector: pubDate
    -
      name: link
      label: 'Origin link'
      selector: link
    -
      name: summary
      label: Summary
      selector: 'itunes:summary'
    -
      name: image
      label: Image
      selector: 'itunes:image[''href'']'

  ids:
    guid:
      type: string

destination:
  plugin: 'entity:node'

process:
  title: title
  field_remote_url: link
  body: summary
  created:
    plugin: format_date
    from_format: 'D, d M Y H:i:s O'
    to_format: 'U'
    source: pub_date
  status:
    plugin: default_value
    default_value: 1
  type:
    plugin: default_value
    default_value: podcast_episode
```

Comment: I recommend checking here as a good starting point. https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/api/migrate-api/migrate-process-plugins/migrate-process-overview